# How prevent power of numbers in edit text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm creating an application with one text field, but when I enter one number with power it shows an error. I need to prevent the entering of power of a number in an EditText. How can I achieve this?

Edit: I need also english alphabet letters, not only numbers. I want to only prevent power of a number. So `android:inputType="number"` and `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` won't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Three ways that I can think of (choose one, or a combination of them):

1. add this property to your EditText in your XML layout: `android:inputType="number"`
2. set the input text programmatically in your activity class:

   ```
   EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
   et.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
   ```

   you can add a period in there too if you wanted to let the user enter a decimal point. You could even add all of the alphabet letters as well.
3. set  up a text changed listener like the following:

   ```
   final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
   et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
       { 
           String text = et.getText().toString();

           if (text.length() > 0) { // if EditText is not empty
               // if last entered character was "^"
               if (text.substring(text.length() - 1).equals("^"))
               {
                   // last entered text was a caret so take it out
                   et.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
                   et.setSelection(et.length()); // set the cursor to the end
               }
           }   
       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int b, int c) 
       { }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int c, int a) 
       { }

   });
   ```

   Note: `if (text.substring(text.length() - 1).equals("^"))` is optional. You could change `"^"` to whatever character you don't want to be entered into your EditText.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why people vote to close here, that's a valid question.

First of all you should make sure that it's not a reasonable use case to enter input like 4E-13. Could make sense for scientifically orientated applications. If that's the case, change the input parsing logic.

If that isn't the case use a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to prevent the user from entering the text.

Comment: Hi i want to prevent the entering of power of a number in text field.please help me

Comment: just set the field to only accept numbers.

Comment: @DanielBo that doesn't work with every keyboard and could easily lead to an nasty runtime exception.

Comment: but i need also english alphabets.not only numbers.I want only prevent power of a number.

Comment: @user3122468 I already posted a link to the TextWatcher. Look it up, use it. If you expirence troubles while using it post them, but try to figure it out yourself first. What exactly is the pattern of "power of a number"? Is it {number}E{number} or is it {number}^{number}? Either way, just use the text watcher.

Comment: setting this to the edit text works for me on all phones i tested it on. android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Comment: number decimal will only let you enter numbers and a decimal sign. if you want integers only, set it to numbers

Comment: @DanielBo unfortunately, it's not guaranteed to work. Most keyboard use it, but they don't have to. I expierenced problems when Android 2.3 was new.

Comment: If you need alphanumeric input use the onTextChanged event and check with Character.isDigit and Character.isAlphabetic every character in the string.